# As like parser can i take user input as an equation and perform calculation on that basis using PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose User can given input like

case 1 : `__inputA * __inputB / __inputC`

or

case 2: `__inputA + __inputB`

where **__inputA** ,**__inputB**, **__inputC** are fixed set of variables that user can choose but he can only change the equation and choose variable from a fixed set.

so if the Database contains table like

```
input_table
------------------------------------
 - id     - alias_variable - weight
 - 1      - __inputA       - 1
 - 2      - __inputB       - 1
 - 3      - __inputC       - 1
------------------------------------
```

Now if the id contains values like

```
input_value_table    
------------------------------
   id,     userid,     inputid,     value
    1,     2,          1,           10
    2,     2,          2,           10
    3,     2,          3,           10
    4,     3,          1,           20
    5,     3,          2,           30
    6,     3,          3,           40
```

Then

For case 1 and userid 2

```
(10*1)*(10*1)/(10*1) = 10
```

and For case 2 and userid 3

```
(20*1) + (30*1) = 50
```

What will be the right way to get input from user like an equation form and perform this using PHP and Mysql?

Comment: There are several approaches that could be used. You could lookup the values from the tables using SQL and then perform the calculation, or you could construct a SQL statement that would perform the calculations. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the syntax of your parser?

Answer (score 0):

My personal choice would be to select all the values from the database using SQL and performing the calculation on the php side (easier to understand the code in my opinion).

However, you can do calculations of columns data using sql.

I recommend you read this guide :

http://www.w3resource.com/sql/arithmetic-operators/sql-arithmetic-operators.php

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes !!
store user data on sql . on php side make for each operation a pattern and user fallow your equation patern. or you must indendify  operators from user input ( + ,- ,/ ....) . and make the mathematical logic for each operation on background and show the result . good luck .

Comment: Right to Left or Left to Right ?

Comment: from lef to right.  but if you break down the operation doese mater . on background you must follow the mathematicals rules.